What are the differences between traveling salesman problem with drones (TSP-D) and Capacitated vehicle routing problem (CVRP)?
I am currently working on an project regarding TSP on this article Bouman, Paul C., Niels A. H. Agatz and Marie Schmidt. ”Dynamic programming approaches for the traveling salesman problem with drone.” which talks about TSP-D.
However after searching on internet for quite some time, I can't really understand the differences between TSP-D and CVRP, i have these definitions for both of them :

CVRP : We are given n - 1 nodes, one depot and distances from the
nodes to the depot, as well as between nodes. All nodes have demands
which can be satisfied by the depot. For delivery to the nodes,
trucks with identical capacities are available. The problem is to
find tours for the trucks of minimal total length that satisfy the
node demands without violating truck capacity constraints. The number
of trucks is not specified. Each tour visits a subset of the nodes
and starts and terminates at the depot.
TSP-D : We are given a set of nodes representing customers, one
depot, and distances between each pair of nodes as well as between
nodes and the depot. A truck and one or more drones are available to
perform deliveries to satisfy customer demands. The truck can travel
on roads and carry the drones with it, while the drones can be
deployed from the truck to deliver to nearby customers and then
return to the truck at a specified meeting point. The objective is to
find delivery routes for the truck and drones that minimize the total
delivery time or distance, coordinating their movements without
violating drone range or payload constraints. Each tour starts and
ends at the depot, and the truck and drones work together to
efficiently serve all customer nodes.

I don't see the point of the drones is it able to bypass nodes / go directly from node 1 to 4 without going through 1 - 2 or 1 -3 ?
The article describes only the TSP-D and explain a dynamic approach problem to solve it, and so to test it i would like to create an example of the problem but i don't know where to start.
Thanks a lot and have a great day !

There are two distance functions, $c$, and $c^d$, one for the truck and one for the drone.  There could be a case where the drone distance is much shorter than the truck distance, and hence a node must be served by a drone.
Consider the instance
s——·——·——·——·——t
|  |  |  |  |  |
·  ·  ·  ·  ·  ·

and the vertical edges are very expensive for the truck and very cheap for the drone.

Ohhhh i kind of understand now, indeed if we consider that we have different distance functions then there is a point to the drone.
I am going to try and define this mathematically to create an example thanks !
